# Hyperledger Java SDK working example

Tags: java, hyperledger-fabric

I am currently digging into Hyperledger Fabric and I can't get stuff started with the Java SDK (talking about 1.0.0-beta here). Is there a working example starting from connecting to the Fabric node, doing queries, etc? All I found so far through extensive googling are "let's-write-some-chaincode" examples.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can take a look at the following

-
[Java SDK for Hyperledger Fabric 2.2](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java). In this, there are two files given in the folder "fabric-sdk-java/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration/" ==> End2endAndBackAgainIT.java, End2endIT.java. This can help.

- For a demonstration, refer to Youtube channel video: [End to end Demo](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxfuWVz7jRA)
- For a fabric network which has everything (network & crypto) setup for the E2E demo: [E2E Cli Setup](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric/tree/master/examples/e2e_cli)

**Update on 2020-June-07**

The link above [Java SDK for Hyperledger Fabric 2.2](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java), is a low level SDK for interacting with Hyperledger Fabric.

If your purpose is building Hyperledger Fabric blockchain client applications, then its recommended to use the [Hyperledger Fabric Gateway SDK for Java](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/release-1.4/), a high level API. Its very simple to use, just refer to the code snippet from [2.2]. please refer to the link [how to use](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/#how-to-use)

```
// code snippet from [2.2]
class Sample { 
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
{ 
    // Load an existing wallet holding identities used to access the network. 
    Path walletDirectory = Paths.get("wallet"); 
    Wallet wallet = Wallets.newFileSystemWallet(walletDirectory); 
    // Path to a common connection profile describing the network. 
    Path networkConfigFile = Paths.get("connection.json"); 
    // Configure the gateway connection used to access the network.
    Gateway.Builder builder = Gateway.createBuilder() .identity(wallet, "user1").networkConfig(networkConfigFile); 

    // Create a gateway connection 
    try (Gateway gateway = builder.connect()){ 
        // Obtain a smart contract deployed on the network. 
        Network network = gateway.getNetwork("mychannel"); 
        Contract contract = network.getContract("fabcar"); 
        // Submit transactions that store state to the ledger. 
        byte[] createCarResult = contract.createTransaction("createCar").submit("CAR10", "VW", "Polo", "Grey","Mary"); 
        System.out.println(new String(createCarResult, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
        // Evaluate transactions that query state from the ledger. 
        byte[] queryAllCarsResult = contract.evaluateTransaction("queryAllCars");
        System.out.println(new String(queryAllCarsResult, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)); 
    } 
    catch (ContractException | TimeoutException | InterruptedException e) { 
        e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

}

API documentation for both [1.4](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/) and [2.2](https://hyperledger.github.io/fabric-gateway-java/master/) are available.

Answer (score 15):

Here is an example, implementing some functionality from fabcar (query.js and invoke.js - only query by one car and change owner)

I used Java8 on Windows. If you use another OS please update paths accordingly.

I used no implementation for json to avoid additional libraries (it is required to deal with certs a bit - see below).

You will need fabcar example up and running.
And (because of 'no json'):

1. Put Private key (cd96d5260ad4757551ed4a5a991e62130f8008a0bf996e4e4b84cd097a747fec-priv from example) to c:\tmp\cert\PeerAdm.priv
2. Put Certificate from PeerAdmin file (value of json's "certificate", with '\n' replaced by newlines) to c:\tmp\cert\PeerAdm.cert

The code (fabrictest/fabcar/Program.java):

```
package fabrictest.fabcar;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;

import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ChaincodeID;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Channel;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.Enrollment;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.HFClient;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.ProposalResponse;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.QueryByChaincodeRequest;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.TransactionProposalRequest;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.User;
import org.hyperledger.fabric.sdk.security.CryptoSuite;

public class Program {

    private static HFClient client = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        /*
         * wallet_path: path.join(__dirname, './creds'), user_id: 'PeerAdmin',
         * channel_id: 'mychannel', chaincode_id: 'fabcar', network_url:
         * 'grpc://192.168.99.100:7051', orderer: grpc://192.168.99.100:7050
         * 
         */

        // just new objects, without any payload inside
        client = HFClient.createNewInstance();
        CryptoSuite cs = CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite();
        client.setCryptoSuite(cs);

        // We implement User interface below in code
        // folder c:\tmp\creds should contain PeerAdmin.cert (extracted from HF's fabcar
        // example's PeerAdmin json file)
        // and PeerAdmin.priv (copy from
        // cd96d5260ad4757551ed4a5a991e62130f8008a0bf996e4e4b84cd097a747fec-priv)
        User user = new SampleUser("c:\\tmp\\creds", "PeerAdmin");
        // "Log in"
        client.setUserContext(user);

        // Instantiate channel
        Channel channel = client.newChannel("mychannel");
        channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer", "grpc://192.168.99.100:7051"));
        // It always wants orderer, otherwise even query does not work
        channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer", "grpc://192.168.99.100:7050"));
        channel.initialize();

        // below is querying and setting new owner

        String newOwner = "New Owner #" + new Random(new Date().getTime()).nextInt(999);
        System.out.println("New owner is '" + newOwner + "'\n");

        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");
        updateCarOwner(channel, "CAR1", newOwner, false);

        System.out.println("after request for transaction without commit");
        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");
        updateCarOwner(channel, "CAR1", newOwner, true);

        System.out.println("after request for transaction WITH commit");
        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");

        System.out.println("Sleeping 5s");
        Thread.sleep(5000); // 5secs
        queryFabcar(channel, "CAR1");
        System.out.println("all done");
    }

    private static void queryFabcar(Channel channel, String key) throws Exception {
        QueryByChaincodeRequest req = client.newQueryProposalRequest();
        ChaincodeID cid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("fabcar").build();
        req.setChaincodeID(cid);
        req.setFcn("queryCar");
        req.setArgs(new String[] { key });
        System.out.println("Querying for " + key);
        Collection<ProposalResponse> resps = channel.queryByChaincode(req);
        for (ProposalResponse resp : resps) {
            String payload = new String(resp.getChaincodeActionResponsePayload());
            System.out.println("response: " + payload);
        }

    }

    private static void updateCarOwner(Channel channel, String key, String newOwner, Boolean doCommit)
            throws Exception {
        TransactionProposalRequest req = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();
        ChaincodeID cid = ChaincodeID.newBuilder().setName("fabcar").build();
        req.setChaincodeID(cid);
        req.setFcn("changeCarOwner");
        req.setArgs(new String[] { key, newOwner });
        System.out.println("Executing for " + key);
        Collection<ProposalResponse> resps = channel.sendTransactionProposal(req);
        if (doCommit) {
            channel.sendTransaction(resps);
        }
    }

}

/***
 * Implementation of user. main business logic (as for fabcar example) is in
 * getEnrollment - get user's private key and cert
 * 
 */
class SampleUser implements User {
    private final String certFolder;
    private final String userName;

    public SampleUser(String certFolder, String userName) {
        this.certFolder = certFolder;
        this.userName = userName;
    }

    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return userName;
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> getRoles() {
        return new HashSet<String>();
    }

    @Override
    public String getAccount() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public String getAffiliation() {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
        return new Enrollment() {

            @Override
            public PrivateKey getKey() {
                try {
                    return loadPrivateKey(Paths.get(certFolder, userName + ".priv"));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public String getCert() {
                try {
                    return new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(certFolder, userName + ".cert")));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return "";
                }
            }

        };
    }

    @Override
    public String getMspId() {
        return "Org1MSP";
    }
    /***
     * loading private key from .pem-formatted file, ECDSA algorithm
     * (from some example on StackOverflow, slightly changed)
     * @param fileName - file with the key
     * @return Private Key usable
     * @throws IOException
     * @throws GeneralSecurityException
     */
    public static PrivateKey loadPrivateKey(Path fileName) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        PrivateKey key = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            is = new FileInputStream(fileName.toString());
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            boolean inKey = false;
            for (String line = br.readLine(); line != null; line = br.readLine()) {
                if (!inKey) {
                    if (line.startsWith("-----BEGIN ") && line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")) {
                        inKey = true;
                    }
                    continue;
                } else {
                    if (line.startsWith("-----END ") && line.endsWith(" PRIVATE KEY-----")) {
                        inKey = false;
                        break;
                    }
                    builder.append(line);
                }
            }
            //
            byte[] encoded = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(builder.toString());
            PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(encoded);
            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA");
            key = kf.generatePrivate(keySpec);
        } finally {
            is.close();
        }
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Dmitry +1 for the answer! Can you please provide a github url for the project e.g. the complete setup of the project. Did you use maven and which version of Java SDK did you use?

Comment: As for JDK it is jdk1.8.0_121

Comment: There is no github for the project, it is just my exersice in fabric. It depends on fabric-sdk-java, I got it from https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java.git

Comment: All fabric setup is from fabcar example, https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples.git ; ./startFabric.sh does all setup

Comment: I got `java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: ECDSA KeyFactory not available` using java8

Comment: Problem solved by changing `KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDSA");` to `KeyFactory.getInstance("EC");`

Answer (score 2):

I find this Java example to be more helpful than the links provided. Out of the box it provides you with an end to end test without bloat. Shows you how to do everything without CLI, in plain Java.

https://github.com/venugopv/FabricJavaSDKSample

Comment: Hi Gamer!  I'm trying to get that code going, I do have the docker image up though it doesnt give any useful debug,just shows
`$ docker-compose up -d
Creating network "sdkintegration_default" with the default driver
Creating sdkintegration_ccenv_1 ...
Creating orderer.example.com ...
Creating ca_peerOrg2 ...
Creating ca_peerOrg1 ...
Creating sdkintegration_ccenv_1
Creating orderer.example.com
Creating ca_peerOrg2
Creating sdkintegration_ccenv_1 ... done
`

Comment: When running mvn packge... I get an error of:
`Connect to localhost:7054 [localhost/127.0.0.1, localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1] failed: Connection refused: connect`

We're you able to overcome this?

I was able to get the docker-compose from [here](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-chaincode-for-java-developers/index.html) to work with no issues - connection wise that is - but the other examples arent working for it.  Thoughts are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Nevermind gamer!  I was able to get this working for the most part [fabric-sdk-java](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java) - thank you!